# How to convert JSON array into object list in the c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a json object as below and I wants to convert it into

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1114,
        "ParentId": 45333,
        "IsActive": true,
        "Name": "John",
        "Contact": "123456"           
    },
    {
        "Id": 11344,
        "ParentId": 54434,
        "IsActive": false,
        "Name": "Levi",
        "Contact": "53552333"
    },
    {
        "Id": 124433,
        "ParentId": 535233,
        "IsActive": false,
        "Name": "Larry",
        "Contact": "5443554"
    }

  ]
```

}

I have tried below option but I am getting error "No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'MyApp.Emp[]'."

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Emp[] acc = js.Deserialize<Emp[]>(json);
```

Below is my Emp class

```
 public class Emp
{
    public Emp()
    { 

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone please show me how I can do it successfully.

Thanks

Comment: As the error says, do you have a constructor in your EMP class with no parameters?

Comment: oThanks Lex for response but why should I need constructor.

Comment: The deserializer requires a constructor in order to make an instance of the class for you to use.

Comment: I have added a constructor in the Emp class but still not working, same error is coming.

Comment: It's not complaining about Emp, it's complaining because you cannot create an array without specifying a size. As Sam I am says, try using List<Emp> instead.

Comment: @CraigH completely wrong....`List<Emp>` or `Emp[]`, JavaScriptSerializer will work correctly after adding parameterless contructor. Try `var ints = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<int[]>("[1,2,3]");`

Comment: well, I have added parameterless constructor and also tried with List<Emp> but still same issue.

Comment: @SyedArib How about posting your code and `Emp` class..

Comment: @Eser I have added my class.

Comment: @SyedArib Given your json and Emp class, I tested it. your code works... So I vote  to close as *not reproducable*

Comment: @Eser, Its good to hear that its working at your end but the fact is the same line of codes are still not working for me. It would be great if you could paste the code here so that i could try it out and see where I am making mistake.

Comment: @SyedArib your json, your deserialization code, your Emp class. I didn't add anything....

Comment: @Eser could you write your solution in an answer? Just want to de-clutter the comments section.

Comment: it worked for me too. Didn't change anything, just worked out-of-the-box

Comment: @neverendingqs solution is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this answer is your want

PS : output

```
public JsonResult SaveResult()
{    
        return Json(new { err = "***"});    
}
```

PS: input

```
public JsonResult ReadResult()
        {
            Object1 xxx = new Object1();
            Object2 aa = new Object2();
            xxx.x2.Add(aa);
            aa = new Object2();
            aa.y = "200";
            aa.z = "222";
            xxx.x2.Add(aa);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(xxx, Formatting.None);


            return Json(json);
        }


        public class Object1
        {
            public string x1 = "aaaaa";
            public IList<Object2> x2 = new List<Object2>();
        }
        public class Object2
        {
            public string y = "100";
            public string z = "10";
        }
```